# Insert graphics, show one after the other with the same positio

Tags: beamer, graphics, subfloats

I would like to have several graphics on one slide, which is then displayed one after the other, which works until now (see MWE). The problem is that I would like to have the images in the same place, i.e. that they are then in the same position as when they are all displayed. They move around to always be in the centre. What would I have to change in the source code to do this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,%
aspectratio=1609,%
]{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{TITLE}
        \begin{figure}%
            \subfloat{\includegraphics<1->[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\qquad%
            \subfloat{\includegraphics<2->[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-b}}\qquad%
            \subfloat{\includegraphics<3->[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-c}}%
        \end{figure}    
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\visible<>{...}` macro. This macro will ensure that the content still occupies space on the overlays where it is not visible.

```
\documentclass[10pt,%
aspectratio=1609,%
]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{TITLE}
        \begin{figure}%
            \visible<1->{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\qquad%
            \visible<2->{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-b}}\qquad%
            \visible<3->{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-c}}%
        \end{figure}    
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]